# Native VLAN Mismatch between two access ports on cisco switches

Tags: cisco, vlan

Ok, I have a cable between two cisco switches. The port on switch A is configured as switchport access vlan 2 and the port on switch B is configured as switchport access vlan 3. For the sake of the current question let's say I cannot change the number of these access vlans. Also, because these are access ports, traffic should be untagged and a trunk is not formed.  Traffic is successfully transferred between switches.

However, I am getting a "Native Vlan Mismatch" error.

Aren't these mismatches generally shown only when a trunk is formed?

Will the same problems associated with trunks and a native vlan mismatch occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDP (LLDP) lists how the each port is configured. Cisco, in their infinite wisdom, thinks access ports in different VLANs are an error. They aren't, but it could be a misconfiguration. Disable CDP and the switch will shut up about it.